# Minimum Distance Problem with several points

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Here is Heron's Shortest Distance Problem:

"Given two points $A$ and $B$ on one side of a line, find $C$ a point on the straight line, that minimizes $AC+BC$".

The answer is solved by the symmetry technique(See [Heron's shortest distance problem](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/historical-activities-for-calculus-module-3-optimization-herons-shortest-distance-problem)).

I am interested in extending this problem as follows:
"Given $n$ points $A_1,...,A_n$ on one side of a line, find $C$ a point on the x-axis, that minimizes $A_1C+A_2C+...+A_nC$".

Is there a geometric approach to answer this question? Even for three points is very interesting. Note that using derivatives needs lots of calculations.

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median

Comment: As Yves has mentioned, this problem seems to be very much related to finding the geometric median. I am not sure if there is an easy way to geometrically find the geometric median using simple geometric tools.
But, the difference here is that you are constraining the geometric median to be on a line. 
In this case, the optimal point should satisfy $\sum_i \cos(\theta_i) = 0$, where $\theta_i$ is the angle between the positive side of the x-axis and the vector that connects the optimal median to the i-th point. This is still algebraic and not geometric.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501158/prove-that-there-is-only-a-single-point-of-minimum-distance-for-n3-points This does not answer the question but is a related question that might interest you. It proves the uniqueness of such a point in existence. For the case of 3 points you might want to look up fermat point

Comment: @Alex Ravsky, Maziar Sanjabi, avz2611 Thank you for your kindly comments!

Answer (score 3):

If a geometric solution would require a straightedge-and-compass construction, then the answer is no.

Consider the simple case of $A_1=A_2=(0,1)$, $A_3=(1,\sqrt{2})$.  Then the exact minimum for $C$ occurs at $(x,0)$ where we or [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B2sqrt%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2Bsqrt%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2B2%29%2Cx%5D%3D%3D0) can calculate

[image]

The cube roots show that this is not a constructible number, and in that sense there is no geometric solution to the problem.

Comment: What a wonderful answer! Thank you very much!